# ng2-pdfjs-viewer print function prints the entire html page rather than the embedded pdf document within the viewer

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

I am using the ng2-pdfjs-viewer extension to embed a pdf document within a page so that I can print the document. It works fine on browsers. However, it tries to print the entire html page on android and ios devices. I am using Angular 5.2.0 with .Net Core.

Here is the html tag:

```
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer #pdfViewerOnDemand
                  [pdfSrc]="pdfDoc"
                  [downloadFileName]="'pdfDoc.pdf'"
                  [download]="true"
                  [print]="true">
</ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug and does not seem to have worked before on mobile devices. I have opened an issue on github for those who come across this issue in the near future: https://github.com/intbot/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/issues/76